# log function in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run following query.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_variables AS SELECT 
   0.99::numeric(10,8) AS y ;

select y, log(y) from tmp_variables
```

It gives me  following error. Is there a way to get around this?

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
Warnings:
Function "log(numeric,numeric)" not supported.
```

Comment: Your error message is suggesting that you are calling `log()` with two arguments.  Your code only has one.  That is strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround is to use "float" instead.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_variables AS SELECT 
   0.99::float AS y ;
select y, log(y) from tmp_variables
```

works fine and returns

> y           log
>
> 0.99  -0.004364805402450088

Comment: This isn't a bug, the OP is passing the wrong data type to the function. Casting the value to float or double precision is the correct approach.

Comment: Nathan, yes you are correct. according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOG.html. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The [LOG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOG.html) function requires an argument that is data type "double precision". Your code is passing in a data type of "numeric", that's why you are getting an error.

This will work:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_variables AS 
   SELECT 0.99::numeric(10,8) AS y ;

select y, log(cast(y as double precision)) from tmp_variables;
```